# Exclude Soundcloud from javascript code

Tags: javascript, iframe, soundcloud

Recently implented this javascript code in order to make all my video embeds the same size as my images. [bhyphen.com](http://www.bhyphen.com)

```
<script language='javascript' src='https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.6.4/jquery.min.js' type='text/javascript'/>
<script type='text/javascript'>//<![CDATA[

$(document).ready(function() {
 // change the dimension variable below to be the column size you want
 var newwidth= 660;
 // this identifies the post-body div element, finds each image in it, and resizes it
 $('.post-body').find('iframe').each(function(n, iframe){
  var iframe = $(iframe);

  var height = iframe.attr('height');
  var width = iframe.attr('width');
  var newHeight = (height/width * newwidth).toFixed(0);
  iframe.attr('width',newwidth).attr('height',newHeight);
 });


});
//]]></script>
```

This code as also affected my Soundcloud embeds as well. Is there a piece of code I can add so that the iframes from my SC embeds will be ignored?

Answer (score 0):

Instead of `$('.post-body').find('iframe)` try classing your Soundcloud and Videos separately:

```
$('post-body').find('#iframe-videos')
```

With your iframe changed to `<iframe class='iframe-videos'>`

That way your script will only affect your videos, not all iframes.

Comment: Is there a way for me to do this without changing the actual code on several blog posts?